# jQuery -onClick - How to change background on every page on website

Tags: jquery, html, toggleclass

I'm using jQuery toggleClass to change body background of the page when particular img link is clicked.
HTML:

```
    <a href="#"><img class="img1" src="[...]" id="b-w"></img></a>
```

CSS:

```
    .black-white{
    background: #000000;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
    $( function() {
    $('#b-w').click( function() {
    $('body').toggleClass("black-white");
    });
    });
```

Now, that works perfect, but only for the current page. The thing that I want is this: Every page on my site should change color to black and stay like that until the particular img link is clicked again, so browsing through site's pages wont change that style.

I did not found any solution on web, and my time is running out, so I cant play with it. If anyone had similar situation, or have an idea how to solve it - please respond..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options, you can save the background color between pages using:

- cookies
- HTML5 Local Storage
- Server sessions

Comment: I have improved my code and now looks like this:  

        <a href="#" onclick="changeBackground('black')"><img                             class="img1" id="b-w"></img></a>

        <script type = "text/javascript">
 function changeBackground(color) {
 localStorage.color = document.body.style.background =    color;
};
    changeBackground(localStorage.color);
 </script>  

This works, it changes body background color for all pages. The thing that is left to resolve is this: If particular img link is clicked again, change back the style to default (white). Something similar to toggle.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save what color the background should be in storage, like a database or localStorage. Then retrieve and set that value when each page loads.